# How to populate index from JSON

Tags: javascript

I have ajax call to JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'file.json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(answer) {
        alert(answer);                                  
    },
    error: function(answer) {
        alert("Error")
    }
});
```

and a JSON file:

```
{
  "saveTime": 1396522039
}
```

I want to get alert not a value of "saveTime" but volue of object. I mean the result of alert must be exactly "saveTime".

Appreciate your help.

Comment: alert(answer.saveTime) ?

Comment: Do you want get properties names from response object?

Comment: Lukasz. Yes. This is what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this for get property name**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'file.json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(answer) {
        for (prop in answer) {
          alert(prop); // alert property name => saveTime                                  
        }
    },
    error: function(answer) {
        alert("Error")
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this you get saveTime:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'file.json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(answer) {
         $.each(answer, function(key, val) {
                 console.log('Key: '+key+'  Val: '+val);
        });

    },
    error: function(answer) {
        alert("Error")
    }
});
```

Comment: That giving me value of saveTime = 1396522039. I want to get exactly result "saveTime" not the value of this

Comment: you want value or key

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
var keys = Object.keys(answer); // This will return all keys of an object as an array.
```

now use it as

```
alert(keys[0]);
```